# Firebase functions FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an app with Firebase and as they added functions I wanted to try this out but ran into a few errors as I am unfamiliar with this language... I'm trying to send an FCM to every user of a group (when a new one is added to the database) and I used the example I found online but still ran into some trouble.

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/groups/{groupId}').onWrite(event => {

const groupId = event.params.groupId;

... // defining constants like msg

const participators = admin.database().ref('/groups/' + groupId + '/users').once('value');
let getDeviceTokensPromise = []
for (let part in participators) {

    getDeviceTokensPromise.push(admin.database().ref('/users/' + part + '/notificationtoken')).once('value');

}

return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, participators]).then(results => {

    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const follower = results[1];

    // Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

        return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');

    }

    console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
    console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

// Notification details.
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New meeting!',
            body: msg
        }
    };

// Listing all tokens.
const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

// Send notifications to all tokens.
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  ...
```

So I guess my mistake must be in the first few lines as all the rest follows this code (I left out the unimportant bits)... Here is my firebase architecture:

[The groups branch of the firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ouK.png)

[One user under the branch users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sPt.png)

Regards

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "/groups/${groupId}/users". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]" 
 that's the first one

Comment: and than another one: TypeError: tokensSnapshot.val is not a function

Comment: Where do you get these errors? In your client app?

Comment: In the log console of firebase...

Comment: This means that the ${groupId} is either null or contains an invalid character.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just change the following

```
const participators = admin.database().ref('/groups/' + groupId + '/users').once('value');
```

and

```
getDeviceTokensPromise.push(admin.database().ref('/users/' + part + '/notificationtoken')).once('value');
```

to these :-

```
const participators = admin.database().ref(`/groups/${groupId}/users`).once('value');
```

and

```
getDeviceTokensPromise.push(admin.database().ref(`/users/${part}/notificationtoken`)).once('value');
```

Also, make sure that you use `` and not  ' ' inside the ref part.

Comment: thnx Rohan for your help! It solved some of the issues but I still get an error message that tokensSnapchot.hasChildren is not a function at Promise.all.then.results

Comment: Could this be caused by the way I made the list getDeviceTokensPromise?